# How to deserialize an API response with the same name but different type

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api

I'm having trouble with de-serializing an API response. The response returns an object. One of the property's in that object can either be a boolean or an object. When de-serializing it in C# I get an de-serialization error. How do i differentiate between the two data types?

Deserializer:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<ApiResponse>>(response)
```

ApiResponse Object:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
  [JsonPropertyName("site")]
  public bool SiteBool { get; set; }
    
  [JsonPropertyName("site")]
  public SiteObject Site { get; set; }
}
    
public class SiteObject
{
  [JsonPropertyName("id")]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  [JsonPropertyName("url")]
  public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use `object` or `dynamic`. C# doesn't have a union types so you just choose a type that is an upper bound

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Using dynamic seems to negate the de-serialization error!

Comment: @devNull InvalidOperationException: The JSON property name for 'ApiResonse.SiteObject' collides with another property.

Comment: You have to create one property only and remove the other one

Comment: You can't have two properties mapped to the same JSON name.  But what serializer are you using?  Is it [tag:System.Text.Json]?

Comment: @dbc yes he's using System.Text.Json.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `JsonConverter` for this purpose, classes would be sth like this:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
  [JsonPropertyName("site")]
  [JsonConverter(typeof(SiteJsonConverter))]
  public ISite Site { get; set; }
   
}
    

public class IsSite : ISite
{
  public bool Value { get; set; }
}

public class SiteObject : ISite
{
  public string Id { get; set; }

  public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

And converter like this, but to implement the converter properly I suggest you to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to

```
public class SiteJsonConverter : JsonConverter<ISite>
{
    public override ISite Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type typeToConvert,
            JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
       //Add conversion code here 
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            DateTimeOffset dateTimeValue,
            JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This code is just an example to show the idea, you need to adjust it to your need